# Difference between setup.py files

Tags: python

If I were to develop and distribute a python package, I know I can probably make a setup.py file like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1', 
      packages=find_packages()
)
```

However, when I look at the setup.py in some installed packages on my PC. It is written quite differently. For instance, setup.py in Scipy looks like:

```
def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
    from scipy._build_utils.system_info import get_info, NotFoundError
    lapack_opt = get_info("lapack_opt")

    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration('scipy',parent_package,top_path)
    config.add_subpackage('cluster')
    config.add_subpackage('constants')
    config.add_subpackage('fft')
    config.add_subpackage('fftpack')
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
    config.add_subpackage('interpolate')
    config.add_subpackage('io')
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    config.add_data_files('*.pxd')
    config.add_subpackage('misc')
    config.add_subpackage('odr')
    config.add_subpackage('optimize')
    config.add_subpackage('signal')
    config.add_subpackage('sparse')
    config.add_subpackage('spatial')
    config.add_subpackage('special')
    config.add_subpackage('stats')
    config.add_subpackage('ndimage')
    config.add_subpackage('_build_utils')
    config.add_subpackage('_lib')
    config.make_config_py()
    return config


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

Can anyone please explain why and which style I should use when developing my own packages?

Comment: You should keep it simple and follow the Python packaging guidelines until you decide you *need* something more elaborate. To look at something super complex like Scipy and think "should I do all of that stuff without understanding why it is there?" is absolutely the wrong way to go about things.

Comment: `scipy` is a very complicated package.  It is perhaps not a good example for a simple release.